# Ruby - Assign key value hash pairs to existing variables

Tags: ruby

How to assign key value pairs to exiting hash? I have the following code and I want to append some key value pairs to `result` variable.

```
            def extra_variables
              result = ansible_vars_from_objects(@handle.object, {})
              result = ansible_vars_from_options(result)
              @handle.log(:info, "Extra vars is:  #{result}")
              ansible_vars_from_ws_values(result)
            end
```

Here is the log output of the result variable:

```
[----] I, [2022-03-08T21:31:41.701307 #322:2acf0cb72fb8]  INFO -- automation: Q-task_id([r345_miq_provision_1235]) <AEMethod launch_ansible_job> Extra vars is:  {"ansible_ssh_user"=>"ubuntu"}
```

Comment: You can use .merge like: `result = ansible_vars_from_objects(@handle.object, {}).merge(ansible_vars_from_options(result))`

Answer (score 0):

### Use the `Hash#merge!` Method

There's a built-in method for merging a Hash object into another Hash in-place: [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21). The main caveat is that Hash objects must have unique keys, so keep this in mind if you're trying to merge objects with the same top-level keys because the last key in the insertion order wins.

For example:

```rb
hash = {a: 1, b:2}
other_hash = {c: 3}
hash.merge! other_hash

hash
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

#### Watch Out for Parsing Issues When Merging Hash Literals

Also note that if you're trying to merge Hash literals, you'll need to enclose the Hash in parentheses so that the interpreter doesn't think you're trying to pass a block. For example, you'd need to use:

```
hash.merge!({d: 4})
```

to avoid Ruby thinkings `{d: 4}` was a block passed to #merge!, but so far as I know this isn't a problem in any currently-supported Ruby when using a variable as the argument to #merge!. However, it's something to keep in mind if you get an exception like:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (SyntaxError)

which is pretty uninformative, but as of Ruby 3.1.1 that's the exception raised by this particular parsing issue.